# Animate view dimensions using Property Animation

Tags: android, animation

Is it possible to animate width and height of a view with the Property Animation framework of android?

For example, let's say I have a view in a xml layout with layout_width=0dp. I want to animate it resulting in layout_width=20dp.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can animate the view in android by getting the id

for example if you want to animate the ImageView it automatically animate corresponding to its width and height,but you if your `layout_width` is 0dp then it **not visible**.

```
ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

TranslateAnimation anim=new TranslateAnimation(0,80,0,0);
        anim.setDuration(1000);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
     // anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);

        imgv.setAnimation(anim);
```